# To Adjust Brightness-Contrast in Plane with Gimp/ImageMagick/...?

Tags: images, imagemagick, image-manipulation, gimp, image-editor

This kind of plane is a common tool used to view Rontgen pictures in Radiology. 
It exists as a standard in many RTG programs in hospitals. 
I would like to have a similar tool open-source for inspecting pictures.

Situation: to have a plane of contrast-brightness adjustments
Motivation: need to adjust continuously contrast-brightness such that Gimp's default tools are not enough fast and not sure if Imagemagick's browser can be extended with it
Proposal: have a plane where you can adjust brightness and contrast in a plane by using some Gimp macros, since I think you cannot extend ImageMagick for it
Nicknames: a nonlinear plane of regression, a nonlinear plane of contrast and brigthness, ...
Characteristics: mouse/keyboard control in the plane

- x-axis: x_left for brightness min, x_right for brightness max
- y-axis: y-bottom for contrast min, y_top for contrast max

### ImageMagick's browser and Gimp

You browse image and its parts by the script about [How Open Specific Part of .png Figure in Ubuntu's Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/a/803012/25388) by keys (\up,\down,\left,\right) or use your mouse to choose the appropriate location. Start the image in the script by `reviewImage 960 raw.png` or manually adjust those settings in Gimp, respectively:
Fig. 1 Starting image by `reviewImage 960 raw.png` in Terminal ImageMagick, Fig. 2 Changing Brightness-Contrast in Palette of Gimp

[image]
   [image]

Jansen's proposal in *Colours > Curves* is great but I would like to have a one-liner to start it in Terminal because it is so important tool for me. Can you? 
Fig. 3 Gimp Colours > Curves

[image]

System: Debian 8.5, Linux Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit
ImageMagick: Date: 2009/01/10 01:00:00
Gimp: 2.8.16

Comment: so you want a two-dmensional contol with brightness one way and contrast the other?  OTOH I find the gimp `colours->curves` does what i want fast enough

Comment: @Jasen Is there any one-liner to start Gimp in that mode? I updated the body.

Comment: not as far as I know